# Swift Final Classes and Functions

Tags: swift, performance, final

This may seem like a trivial question about performance, but in Swift, if you declare a class as `final` is it necessary to also declare all of its methods as `final` or is that just a superfluous redundancy? I just want to make sure my concrete classes run as `final` to maximize security and performance in my app. Thanks for any tips, wisdom, or knowledge in advance!

Comment: Dang. Already been asked

Comment: When you turn on "Whole module optimization" in the compiler build settings then this has a similar effect. But it's done by the compiler for you and you don't have to mark all clases as final. The drawback: it only works for apps, not for libraries and it dramatically increases the build time. But it could be done e.g. only for RELEASE builds.

Comment: @Darko what is 'ma' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Swift if you declare class as final is it necessary to also declare all of its methods as final or is that just a superfluous redundancy

Yes, it's redundant. If the class is final, all its members are final by implication. You are getting the efficiency of avoiding dynamic dispatch, and what's what you want to do.

Comment: So basically no need to make those methods final?

Comment: Correct, because in what way could you override one of those methods? You can't make a subclass, so there's no place to do an override.